# Complex .htaccess redirect advice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all users who visit pages on my old domain to the same page on my new domain (only the domain name is changing).

If my old domain is www.OLDDOMAIN.com and my new domain is www.NEWDOMAIN.com then I want to be able to redirect visitors who visit www.OLDDOMAIN.com/c/123/Page-Name to www.NEWDOMAIN.com/c/123/Page-Name (note that these are SEO friendly URLs and not simply sub directories or filenames)

However, I do not want this rule to apply to visitors from a certain IP addresses (lets say 2 IP address 123.123.123.123 and 345.345.345.345 - I appreciate these aren't valid).

I would also like to ensure that all subdomains e.g. files.OLDDOMAIN.com are NOT redirected to files.NEWDOMAIN.com

AND I would like the ability to add exclusions to this rule. E.g. I want to continue to be able to access www.OLDDOMAIN.com/index.php or a subfolder e.g. www.OLDDOMAIN.COM/admin/

The reason for need to do this is the website currently on www.OLDDOMAIN.com is being moved to www.NEWDOMAIN.com. and www.OLDDOMAIN.com is being repurposed for another website. The reason I need the redirects is to retain search engine rankings, at least until the new site is established. The solution therefore needs to be SEO friendly.

Apologies in advance for not supplying any code but I'm not entirely sure where to start with this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# exclude these IPs
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.123\.123\.123|345\.345\.345\.345)$

# exclude these URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(/index\.php|admin/) [NC]

# exclude sub-domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]

# redirect to new host
RewriteRule ^ http://www.NEWDOMAIN.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your answer. Now if I had about 1000 unique pages. Would it be better to list these as individual 302 redirects or use your solution. I'm just thinking about in the future about error pages (404 etc.) as these obviously wouldn't work if the visitor is redirected straight to the new domain? Also, do you think this improve or decrease the speed of the website?

Comment: You mean you want to exclude 1000 pages from this redirect or want to redirect these 1000 unique pages to new domain?

Comment: I want to redirect only the 1000 unique pages to the new domain

Comment: I think I'd prefer to use your original solution but I'm just wondering which option you think would be best...

Comment: Rather than having 1000 redirect rules I think using `RewriteMap` might be better (if you have access to Apache config).

Comment: I will take a look at RewriteMap. Thanks for the pointer. In the meantime, how would I add multiple subdomains to the list of excluded subdomains e.g. folder1.OLDDOMAIN.com, folder2.OLDDOMAIN.com. and would you recommend including .htaccess and .htpasswds to the list of excluded URIs?

Comment: If you have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]` then all the sub-domains will be excluded as it will match `www.olddomain.com` or `olddomain.com`